# how to delete or hide a li

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
<li>ff<strong>foobar</strong><a class="icon-close" href="#."></a></li>
```

On clicking the `a`, the respective `li` should be deleted.

`$(.close-icon).hide();` hides every thing.

Comment: work on accep rate..accept some useful/satisfied  answer of your questions including this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".close-icon").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

This will not only hide the element, it will also remove it from the page.

Comment: this code only removes the "a" element and not the li.
The question states the li is to be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Should work, but haven't tested:

```
$("a.close-icon").click(function() {
  $(this).parent("li").hide();
});
```

Comment: parent could be a little dangerous if the HTML structure is modified, why don't you use `closest()`?

Answer (score 2):

try

#### hide:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").hide(); 
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QPpDu/)

#### remove :

```
 $("a").click(function() {
      $(this).closest("li").empty(); 
 });
```

OR

```
$("a").click(function() {
      $(this).closest("li").remove(); 
   });
```

### Reference

- [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this

```
 $('.close-icon').click( function (){ $(this).hide(); });
```

For hiding the entire parent

```
 $('.close-icon').click( function (){ $(this).parent('li').hide(); });
```

Also change `.close-icon` to `'.close-icon'`

for `removing` replace `hide()` by `remove()`

Comment: @meo the OP doesn't explicitly tell this

Comment: what about: "On clicking hte href respective li should be deleted." :P

Comment: @meo well then `remove()` would be the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$(.icon-close).click( function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you want the li to hide / remove on click of the icon

```
 $('.close-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').hide();
    });
```

or

```
$('.close-icon').click(function(){
$(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide it

```
$('a.icon-close').click(function(){ 
   $(this).parent('li').hide();
});
```

If you want to delete it

```
$('a.icon-close').click(function(){
   $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

The filtering 'li' in `.parent()` is not strictly necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but code below should work, if I understood your requirement.

```
$(.close-icon).click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().remove(); //remove the parent OR 
   //$(this).parent().hide(); //hide the parent

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.close-icon").click(function() {
  $(this).parent("li").remove();
  return false;
});
```